# MS Access - Query Datapertaining to record count

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I have a Microsoft Access 2016 Database with the following tables:

```
Client
  - ID (PK)
  - Name
Store
  - ID (PK)
  - Name
ClientOf
  - ID (PK)
  - Client (FK)
  - Store (FK)
```

A Person can be the client of several Stores, so there might be several entries *ClientOf* the reference on *Client*.
Additionally I have a Form displaying the information of *Client* called *ClientForm*.

Here is what I want:
I want a ListView that displays the Name of all Stores the *Client* is liked with over *ClientOf*.

That means I need to be able to filter the query by the current record count/ID in the Form. How can I do that?

Cheers.

Comment: The easiest way to display the related data on your form would be to use a subform whose data comes from your many-to-many table (ClientOf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is correct.  A query of the 3 tables with the proper joins between PK/FK will have the correct record set.

Really your issue is at the presentation level - as to what form/report object combination do you seek to present the information.  This is probably best referred to in a textbook or instructional online resource.